# How much solar power in kWH is there in the stratosphere during the day?

Tags: energy, estimation, power, sun, solar-cells

The stratosphere is above much of the atmosphere. People have talked about collecting solar energy there and beaming it back to Earth. How much power are we talking about?

Comment: https://www.energy.gov/articles/space-based-solar-power

Comment: Look up the [Solar constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic for apparent lack of previous effort.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the linked article by Thomas Fristch, the relevant value is approximately the solar constant: $1.362\ \mathrm{kW/m^2}$, or in units of more appropriate size for large-scale energy generation, $1.362\ \mathrm{GW/km^2}$. This value is the intensity of solar power falling on a small plane oriented blunt perpendicular to the Sun, *in vacuum*. Because the stratosphere is considerably closer to such a vacuum than at the surface of the Earth, the intensity there will be similar, though actually still a small amount less (not sure how much).

However, this doesn't give the *total* energy over the entire stratosphere - though we wouldn't want to capture that, as it would completely block all sunlight from reaching the Earth's surface. But if you want to calculate it, you also need to take into account the fact the Earth is curved and not a flat disc, which means that those parts closer to the "terminator" (where the Sun is observed to "set" or "rise" when crossing) will receive less illumination, so what you need is to integrate Lambert's cosine law, which basically says that if the surface normal of the confronting plane makes an angle $\theta$ with the line from the Sun's center to its center ($\theta = 0$ is head-on brunt), the intensity it experiences, relative to the full-brunt value $I_0$ (the above solar constant) is

$$I = I_0\ \cos(\theta)$$

so at $\theta = 0$, $I = I_0$, and at $\theta = 90^{\circ}$ ($\frac{1}{4} \tau\ \mathrm{rad}$), it is zero (i.e. we are right at the terminator.) Intuitively, think about a square plane tilted at an angle, and imagine how it "looks" to the beams of sunlight coming at its center as they cross the vacuum of space. Up until very close, they don't "see" that they are approaching a square, but rather what (due to perspective and the skew angle) looks like a squashed rectangle. Hence they hit a smaller area, and the plane receives less total light, and a little trig tells you that the exact dependence is on the cosine, leading to the above formula directly.

Hence it suffices to integrate this over a hemisphere of one Earth radius, in spherical coordinates $(\rho, \theta, \phi)$ where the axis is sticking along the line from the Earth's core to the Sun's:

$$P = \iint_S I_0 \cos(\theta)\ dA = \iint_S I_0 \cos(\theta)\ [R_\oplus d\Omega]$$

which gives

$$\begin{align}
P &= \iint_S I_0 \cos(\theta)\ [R_\oplus^2 d\Omega]\\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} I_0 \cos(\theta) R_\oplus^2 \sin(\theta)\ d\theta\ d\phi\\
&= I_0 R_\oplus^2 \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(\theta)\ \sin(\theta)\ d\theta\ d\phi\\
&= 2\pi I_0 R_\oplus^2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(\theta) \sin(\theta)\ d\theta\end{align}$$

for which a trig sub of $u = \sin(\theta)$, $du = \cos(\theta)\ d\theta$ gives

$$P = 2\pi I_0 R_\oplus^2 \int_{0}^{1} u\ du$$

hence

$$P = \pi R_\oplus^2 I_0$$

which for $R_\oplus = 6357\ \mathrm{km}$ gives $P \approx 1.729 \times 10^8\ \mathrm{GW}$ of total solar energy.